# check if array includes value or includes another value

Tags: javascript, arrays, include, reformatting

```
const isIncluded = ["1","2"]
        .includes("1") || ["1","2"]
        .includes("2") ;
```

how can I reformat this monstrosity in a more elegant way

Answer (score 1):

For checking an array with another array, you could iterate one array and check the value with `includes`.

```
array.some(v => isIncluded.includes(v))
```

Comment: That looks so much better thank you Nina!

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this?

```
const checkIncluded = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.some(item => arr2.includes(item));
```

If any item from arr1 is inside arr2 returns true.

Example:

```
const isIncluded1 = checkIncluded(["1", "2"], ["1","2"]) // true
const isIncluded2 = checkIncluded(["1", "2"], ["1"]) // true
const isIncluded3 = checkIncluded(["1", "2"], ["2"]) // true
const isIncluded4 = checkIncluded(["1", "2"], ["3", "5"]) // false
```